# lazarus - TJSONData path exists

Tags: json, delphi, lazarus

I am trying to work with JSON, but my problem is that I can't find any method for checking if a path exists or get a path list.

For example, my app receives this JSON from a server:

```json
{
    "ok": true,
    "result":[
        {
            "id": 12,
            "first_name": "David",
            "username": "Fake"
        },
        {
            "id": 13,
            "first_name": "John",
            "username": "sample",
            "message":"test msg"
        }
        ,{
            "id": 13,
            "first_name": "David",
            "username": "Fake",
            "text":"test txet"
        }
    ]

}
```

But the data is not equal, for example `John` has a `message` but `David` does not.

Note: If I try to read `message` for everybody, I get an exception in the code.

Here is my code:

```pascal
for i := 0 to jsonDoc.findpath('result').Count - 1 do
begin
  // jsonDoc.findpath('result').Items[i].WHAT IS NEED FOR CHECK ??

  Result[i].text := jsonDoc.findpath('result').Items[i].FindPath('message').AsString; // exception           
end;
```

Please guide me to find a path list or check if a path exists.

Comment: can you use another library? for example it is easy to do in https://github.com/hgourvest/superobject

Comment: @Arioch'The Thx but I have to use native lazarus functions.

Comment: every open-source library is as native as FPC/Lazarus itself, but up to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your use of `findPath('result')` is grossly inefficient.  You should be calling it *one time* and saving the returned object to a local variable.

Second, [`FindPath()`](http://freepascal.org/docs-html/current/fcl/fpjson/tjsondata.findpath.html) returns `nil` if the specified path is not found, but you are not checking for that condition, which is why you are getting an exception when `message` is missing.

Try this instead:

```
var
  jsonDoc, r: TJSONData;
  msg: TJSONData;
  I: Integer;
begin
  jsonDoc := ...;
  r := jsonDoc.findpath('result');
  if r <> nil then
  begin
    for i := 0 to res.Count - 1 do
    begin
      msg := res.Items[i].FindPath('message');
      if msg <> nil then
        Result[i].text := msg.AsString
      else
        Result[i].text := '';
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Please read Lazarus' documentation for more details:

[Reference for unit 'fpjson'](http://freepascal.org/docs-html/current/fcl/fpjson/index.html)

Comment: You are right, and I was add function to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use [my own JSON implementation](https://github.com/deltics/delphi.libs/blob/master/rtl/Deltics.JSON.pas) so am not familiar with the Lazarus JSON implementation specifically, but from the code you have posted it appears that `FindPath('message')` returns NIL if the specified path does not exist.

So instead of unconditionally using the return of `FindPath()`, assign the result to some intermediate variable of the appropriate type and test for **NIL** before trying to access any members:

```
var
   msg: T??;

//...

msg := jsonDoc.findpath('result').Items[i].FindPath('message');
if Assigned(msg) then
    Result[i].text := msg.AsString
else
    Result[i].text := '';  // If necessary

//...
```

For comparison, my JSON library uses **OptXXX** functions for reading values that may not be present on an object (Opt ==> optional) so the equivalent using my implementation would be something like:

```
var
  jsonResults: TJSONArray;

//..

jsonResults := jsonDoc['result'].AsArray;
for i := 0 to Pred(jsonResults.Count) do
  result[i].Text := jsonResults[i].AsObject.OptString('message');
```

However, I have not tested my library with FPC/Lazarus so this code is presented for interest/Delphi developers only, not as a suggestion (for that see initial code snippet above).